# Spring Data REST - Detected multiple association links with same relation type

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to doing a simple Spring app. It needs to expose REST endpoints and save it to a relational database.

I took your sample project, http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/. I am able to do all the operations( POST, PATCH, PUT, GET) as mentioned in your guide.

However I tried creating adding relationships to Person Entity class and things start to fall apart.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private PersonDetails personDetails;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private PersonChildren personChildren;

     ///Getter and setters for everything except id.
}


@Entity
public class PersonChildren {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String childFirstName;
    private String childLastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="personChildren", optional=false)
    private Person person;

///Getter and setters for everything except id.
}


@Entity
public class PersonDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="personDetails",optional=false)
    private Person person;

///Getter and setters for everything except id.
}


@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-rest'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Call:

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "firstName":"John", "lastName": "Doe", "personDetails": { "email": "john@gmail.com", "phoneNumber": "001-002-0003" }, "personChildren": {"childFirstName": "Mary", "childLastName": "Martin" } }' <code> http://localhost:8080/people </code>

Response: 
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
<code>
Location: http://localhost:8080/people/1
</code>
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 26 Jun 2014 05:42:45 GMT

$ curl  http://localhost:8080/people

{
  "timestamp" : 1403761371011,
  "status" : 500,
  "error" : "Internal Server Error",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
  "message" : "Could not write JSON: Detected multiple association links with same relation type! Disambiguate association @javax.persistence.OneToOne(optional=false, targetEntity=void, cascade=[], fetch=EAGER, orphanRemoval=false, mappedBy=personChildren) private com.ds.dao.rest.Person com.ds.dao.rest.PersonChildren.person using @RestResource! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap[\"people\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Detected multiple association links with same relation type! Disambiguate association @javax.persistence.OneToOne(optional=false, targetEntity=void, cascade=[], fetch=EAGER, orphanRemoval=false, mappedBy=personChildren) private com.ds.dao.rest.Person com.ds.dao.rest.PersonChildren.person using @RestResource! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap[\"people\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])",
  "path" : "/people"
}
```

Question 1: I am able to do a post but my GET keeps failing.

Question 2: Why am I getting this error when Post succeeds?

Question 3: Is there a good Spring Guide that will help with REST and JPA? If you are still working on these modules what examples can I look at?

Question 4: Is @RepositoryRestResource the problem? It is not recognized unless I add spring-data-rest-webmvc as dependency.

This is similar to the unanswered question 
[Spring Data Rest Ambiguous Association Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462826/spring-data-rest-ambiguous-association-exception)

**Update**:

It is working with only one `OneToOne` mapping in `Person` class. If I add both classes, `personDetails` and `personChildren` in `Person` with `OneToOne` mapping. It is NOT working.

I also tried adding `@JointColumn(name="person_details")` and `@JointColumn(name="person_children")` to `personDetails` and `personChildren`. It did NOT work either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for that is pretty simple: the relation names for associated entities are derived from the property names of the containing class. So both `PersonDetails` and `PersonChildren` want to create an outbound link to a `Person` named `person`. If we rendered that, it would look something like this

```
{ _links : { 
   person : { href : … }, <- the one from PersonDetails
   person : { href : … }  <- the one from PersonChildren
}
```

This is of course invalid. Also, lining up the two links in an array would not allow you to distinguish between the two links anymore (which one is coming from `PersonDetails` and which one is coming from `PersonChildren`.

So there are a few options here:

1. **Manually name the relations of those types**. You can annotate the `Person` properties with `@RestResource` and configure the `rel` attribute of the annotation to something different than `person`.
2. **You want any of the two not exported at all**. The very same annotation can be used to prevent the link from being rendered at all. Simply set the `exported` flag in `@RestResource` to `false` and the link will not be rendered. This might be useful if the pointer e.g. from `PersonDetails` is just relevant within the code, but actually not in a JSON representation.

Comment: Oliver, this worked like a charm. I used option 1. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I tried both the options, none of them are working from me.