# Spring Data Rest: Detected multiple association links with same relation type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Regarding this question, I checked out [Spring Data Rest Ambiguous Association Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462826/spring-data-rest-ambiguous-association-exception) but couldn't get it to work for me.

As you can see in my code below, I added `@RestResource` annotation with `rel` equal to some other value.

Similar to the question above, POST requests work, but GET requests throw exception about multiple association links with the same relation type:

> "Could not write JSON: Detected multiple association links with same
>   relation type! Disambiguate association
>   @org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource(rel=createdBy,
>   exported=true, path=,
>   description=@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.Description(value=))
>   @javax.persistence.ManyToOne(optional=true, targetEntity=void,
>   cascade=[], fetch=EAGER)
>   @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(referencedColumnName=ASSIGNABLE_ID,
>   nullable=false, unique=false, name=CREATED_BY, updatable=true,
>   columnDefinition=, foreignKey=@javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name=,
>   value=CONSTRAINT, foreignKeyDefinition=), table=, insertable=true)
>   private com.ag.persistence.domain.PersonEntity
>   com.ag.persistence.domain.TeamEntity.createdBy using @RestResource!
>   (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap[\"persons\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Detected multiple
>   association links with same relation type! Disambiguate association
>   @org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource(rel=createdBy,
>   exported=true, path=,
>   description=@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.Description(value=))
>   @javax.persistence.ManyToOne(optional=true, targetEntity=void,
>   cascade=[], fetch=EAGER)
>   @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(referencedColumnName=ASSIGNABLE_ID,
>   nullable=false, unique=false, name=CREATED_BY, updatable=true,
>   columnDefinition=, foreignKey=@javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name=,
>   value=CONSTRAINT, foreignKeyDefinition=), table=, insertable=true)
>   private com.ag.persistence.domain.PersonEntity
>   com.ag.persistence.domain.TeamEntity.createdBy using @RestResource!
>   (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap[\"persons\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])"

The error seems to be happening in this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class TeamEntity extends AssignableEntity {
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    private LocalDateTime modifiedDate;
    private Collection<MembershipEntity> memberships;
    private PersonEntity createdBy;
    private PersonEntity modifiedBy;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    public LocalDateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_DATE")
    public LocalDateTime getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(LocalDateTime modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    public Collection<MembershipEntity> getMemberships() {
        return memberships;
    }

    public void setMemberships(Collection<MembershipEntity> memberships) {
        this.memberships = memberships;
    }

    @RestResource(rel = "team_createdBy")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY", referencedColumnName = "ASSIGNABLE_ID", nullable = false)
    public PersonEntity getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(PersonEntity createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @RestResource(rel = "team_modifiedBy")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MODIFIED_BY", referencedColumnName = "ASSIGNABLE_ID", nullable = false)
    public PersonEntity getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(PersonEntity modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }
}
```

Ironically, I am not accessing this specific resource. I also have other resources with `createdBy` and `modifiedBy`-- is it the one causing this issue?

Comment: Does any other entity have the property `createdBy`? The `PersonEntity`for instance?

Comment: All my entities have the four fields: ``createdBy``, ``modifiedBy``, ``createdDate`` and ``modifiedDate``

Comment: That could be the problem. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426644/spring-data-rest-detected-multiple-association-links-with-same-relation-type). Both `PersonEntity`s in your `TeamEntity` probably expose a link `createdBy`.

Comment: I need these fields for editing-- is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Does PersonEntity and TeamEntity has theirs repositories? Please also paste in those classes.

Comment: In this specific scenario, no, I do not have repositories for this. But I have tried creating an annotated repository to expose an endpoint for those resources which solved this issue, however, I would like to know if there is a way, without exposing an endpoint, to go about this.

Comment: sorry, dont know.. in fact im facing similar issues at the moment.. adding repositories helped but now  created _links make no sense

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you might have `exported = false` on your `PersonEntity` object. Because of this, any references in `PersonEntity` will be added to the `_links` section of your `TeamEntity`. Because both `PersonEntity` objects have a `createdBy` reference, they are colliding with the `TeamEntity.createdBy` reference.

To understand what is happening this example might help:

```
class Answer {
   Question q; //JPA ManyToOne back-reference
}

class Question {
   List<Answer> as; // JPA OneToMany reference
}

class UserAnswer {
   Answer a;
   Question q;
}
```

In my case, because an `Answer` can only exist within a `Question`, we have the following on our `AnswerResource`, to prevent Answers from being exported:

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
```

This causes `Answer` objects to be serialized within the parent object, rather than as a reference in the `_links` section, and this ends up being the cause of the problem....

When `UserAnswer` is serialized, it renders something like this:

```
{
  "answer" : {
    "creationDate" : "2014-09-18T17:28:31.000+0000",
    "modificationDate" : "2014-09-18T17:28:31.000+0000",
    "answerText" : "Vendas",
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9090/data/userAnswers/15"
    },
    "question" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9090/data/userAnswers/15/question"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that "_links.question" above is from the `Answer`!

So if you add a `Question` to `UserAnswer`, you will see the error you are asking about, because the `UserAnswer` itself *also* wants to include a _link reference to a `Question`.

In your case, I think your `PersonEntity` and your `TeamEntity` both have `createdBy` references.

I'm not 100% sure what the solution is yet, I don't know if you can specify hierarchical `rel` names.

Comment: I created a JIRA issue for this as I suspect it's a bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-520

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Add Spring Data repositories for ALL (or at least more of) your entities. (In this case, it sounds like you need to make a PersonRepository).

Long answer:

Spring Data Rest uses _links to avoid sending back the entire JSON tree, but it can only make _links to mapped entities that have Repositories.

If there isn't a repository for an entity, Spring can't use a link and will instead just put the whole JSON object in the response.

I THINK what's happening with this exception is that a lower, second level relationship is being put into a _link, and more than one of these have the same name.

I'm not 100% sure I understand it all, but I had the same exception when only had repositories for a few entities, and when I made a Repository for every single entity the problem vanished.